# Manipulate regex capture group in replacement in VSCode / Sublime

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

In my Javascript file, I want to replace:

```
var user1 = {id: 'Alan Banks'};
var user2 = {id: 'Chris Daily'};
```

with

```
var user1 = {id: 'Alan_Banks'};
var user2 = {id: 'Chris_Daily'};
```

I can match the user names with the following regex in VSCode, Sublime (and Dreamweaver too, out of desperation):

```
id: '(.*?)'
```

So capture group `$1` now holds the content of the `id` property of each user.

How can I perform the second part of my operation, being replacing the spaces in the captured substring with underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Visual Studio Code***, you can use

**Find**: `(?<=id:\s*'[^']*?)\s(?=[^']*')`
**Replace**: `_`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gH06D/1). Details:

- `(?<=id:\s*'[^']*?)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `id:`, 0+ whitespaces,  `'`, and then any 0 or more chars other than `'` as few as possible
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^']*')` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with 0+ chars other than `'` and then `'`.

In ***Sublime Text 3***, that supports PCRE regex search and replace, you can use

**Find**: `(?:\G(?!\A)|id:\s*')[^'\s]*\K\s(?=[^']*')`
**Replace**: `_`

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gH06D/2). Details:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|id:\s*')` - end of the previous match or `id:`, 0+ whitespaces and `'`
- `[^'\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `'` and whitespace
- `\K` - omits all text matched so far
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=[^']*')` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with 0+ chars other than `'` and then `'`.

Comment: Thanks - as a regex beginner, the additional explanations are much appreciated